# I have L2 network in Delhi, can it communicate without router to L2 network in Florida, using only STP protocol,

Tags: spanning-tree

using only STP protocol, no NVE etc should be used, is it feasible

Comment: STP as in spanning-tree protocol? That's not used for communication at all but for preventing bridge loops.

Comment: Did you plug the two networks together with a cable?

Comment: No, i wasnt very clear about STP usage when i posted this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible at all. If you need that kind of solution, you have to have a direct connection between these two locations. It is not a practical solution and therefore you have to use an ISP connection. But you do not need your own router and you can config ISP router based your requirements. L2VPN is also a good solution and it is easy to configure. MPLS is great solution for your problem and you can use the technologies below to achieve your goal.

- VXLAN
- L2VPN
- EVPN

Comment: ok, so that means STP works only till the point there is direct connection

Comment: STP is not really a transport protocol. It is used only for the prevention of layer 2 network loops (frame broadcast storms) from disrupting the service of a local area network. Just a clever mechanism by virtually disconnecting redundant links.